# filling in textarea with jQuery from an element. Almost finished

Tags: jquery

Just need some help here

```
$(document).ready(
          function() {
             $('#submitCart').click(function() {
               var ListItems = $('.theList').text();
               var PriceItems = $('.theList li').attr('data-points');
               var GrandTot = $('.totaler').text();
             $('#message').text(ListItems + PriceItems + GrandTot);
        });
    });
```

So it works, thanks to another post I recently made, I had everything at `.html` instead of `.text`, now my problem is when you click the `#submitCart`

the list comes out like so

```
item2item2item2 2000 total = $6000
```

I want the textarea to read like so

```
Item2 = 2000
Item2 = 2000
Item2 = 2000
Total = $6000
```

how would I do this? I tried making a `<br>` inbetween like so, `+<br>+` which did not work

Anyone have a good suggestion?

Comment: Although not related to your question, I recommend you use lower camel case for your variable assignments. Upper camel case vars are commonly used for constructors within the JS community.

Comment: Why are the items/total put into a textarea as opposed to a read-only element such as a div? Use of a textarea implies that the entries are user editable. Is that the case? This matters as it affects the solution you seek.

Comment: They are inserted into a div first. This is for a gimmick shopping cart for a forum site. Basically there are items for sale, they click, and it goes into a shopping cart, adding the values of each. Once they are satisfied they click a button, this code comes into place, adding the items + price + total and then that data is sent via a pm to the moderator/admin. Thats why :)

Comment: Still doesn't explain to me why a textarea needs to be involved but if you are satisfied that's the right approach, then that's fine.

Comment: theres a hidden form with a textarea to send the private message

Comment: Aha, keyword "hidden" - makes slightly more sense now. Personally I would still avoid textarea in preference to an set of dynamically created `<input type="hidden" name="item[]">` elements. Then jQuery's `form.serialize()` or some custom serialization, will make most of your other problems disappear.

Comment: lol. Yeah I'm a newbie so serialized forms are in the future. I'm self teaching everything, so I'm trying to focus on certain elements right now. Thank you though Beetroot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some work ahead of you .. `.attr` only gets the attribute of the *first* matched element, and even if it did return all of them you would have to parse before concatenation.  Anyway:

```
var text = '';
var total = 0;

$(".theList li").each(function () {
   var string = $(this).text();
   var points = parseInt($(this).data('points'));

   //capitalize first letter of string
   text += string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)
   //add line break at the end
      + ' = ' + points + "\n";

   total += points;
});

//I think calculating total is easier than trying to manipulate $(".totaler")
text += "Total = $" + total;
$("#message").text(text);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer.. I thought 'theList' was a textarea based on his post... obviously, it's a ul

Comment: well the code I have already adds the points for me :) thats why i did it that way in the beginning. And hello again explosion lol. Alright so say that the code I presented above for the addition is already done, so it would work. What would I do for the .attr? I'm trying to study your code so I can learn better. PS, javascript/jQuery newbie (4months)

Comment: @user1760670 There is not much you can do since `.attr` *only* returns the *first* result if it selects multiple elements.  You have to iterate over it somehow (e.g. using `.each` like I do in my answer).

Comment: Yeah, thats why I'm studying your code, how would I implement this to my code? I don't want to just copy and paste, since really there is no learning from that. I see that you added a "/n" which must be the line break for codes. Just trying to understand is all my bad.

Comment: That's good that you want to learn.  `"\n"` is the string for line-break.  What else do you not understand?

Comment: Well, basically the .attr, which I understand only the first found element will be inserted to the textarea. So I'm looking at your code to understand what you did to match repeatively

Comment: @ExplosionPills sorry for the reluctant misunderstands :/ I'd rather update my code, so then I atleast know what I did, and how it works. If that makes sense

Comment: @user1760670 `.attr` returning the first result is a feature of jQuery.  So you have `$("li").attr()` -- there could be multiple `li` elements, so jQuery only returns the result of the first one.  If you want to get each one, you have to iterate over the selector (this is what `$("li").each()` does.  In the function inside of `.each`, `this` is the current element in the iteration (the current `li`) so `$(this).attr()` returns the result of *that* element.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20455/discussion-between-user1760670-and-explosion-pills)